# multiply specific column in a file which consists of thousands columns

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, printf, numeric-data

The in file looks like this

```
-17.3644       0.00000000     0.00000000 ....
-17.2703       0.00000000     0.00000000 ....
-17.1761       0.00000000     0.00000000 ....
-16.5173       0.00000000     0.00000000 ....
-16.4232       0.00000000     0.00000000 ....
```

The desire output should be

```
-173.644       0.00000000     0.00000000 ....
-172.703       0.00000000     0.00000000 ....
-171.761       0.00000000     0.00000000 ....
-165.173       0.00000000     0.00000000 ....
-164.232       0.00000000     0.00000000 ....
```

so I want to multiply let's say 1st column by 10 but on the same time also keep the other 1000 columns. with `awk '{print $1*10}' infile > outfile` you only print first column, how can I also keep the other columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
awk '{$1=$1*10 ; print }'
```

this will change first parameter, and print whole line.

to keep formating to 3 digit, use

```
awk '{$1=sprintf("%.3f",$1*10);print;}'
```

Comment: to add on this, if someone is interested in the format as well awk '{$1=sprintf("%.3f",$1*10);print}'

Comment: tanks, I update with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=open('p.txt','r')
for i in k:
    k=re.sub(' +',' ',i).split(' ')
    print float(k[0])*10,k[1],k[2]
```

output

```
-173.644 0.00000000 0.00000000
-172.703 0.00000000 0.00000000
-171.761 0.00000000 0.00000000
-165.173 0.00000000 0.00000000
-164.232 0.00000000 0.00000000
```

Comment: What if there are 1000 columns?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ < infile tr \- _ |
  dc -e "
    [q]sq
    [SMlN1+sNz1<a]sa
    [LMn32anlN1-dsN0<b]sb
    [?z0=q0sNlax.1/n32anlbx[]pclcx]sc
    3klcx
  "
```

**Output:**

```
-173.644 0 0 0 0 0 0 
-172.703 0 0 0 0 0 0 
-171.761 0 0 0 0 0 0 
-165.173 0 0 0 0 0 0 
-164.232 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

**Brief Explanation:**

The `dc` is a reverse Polish notation `RPN` calculator which stores data on it's main stack.
Store in a named stack M the fields of the current line till you reach only one standing.
Divide it .1 == multiply by 10 AND get scaling applied on the result.
Now regurgitate the stack M and place back on main stack the current line fields which are left unmodified. Keep printing them to stdout at the same time we are popping them off the M stack. At the end of file or upon reaching an empty/blank line, whichever happens first, we quit.